# Using queue to rearrange every other integer

Tags: java

I'm trying to figure out how to take in an integer and rearrange them so that every alternating character is saved (So the [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] would return [1, 4, 2, 5, 3, 6]). I think a queue would be the best to use for this problem so here's what I have so far. It returns [3, 1, 4, 5, 2, 6], but I'm not sure how I can get it to return the alternating form above :

```
import java.util.*;
public class everyOtherInteger {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Queue <Integer> sort = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    String s = "123456";    

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        sort.add(Integer.parseInt(s.charAt(i) + ""));

        if (i%2 == 0) {
            int a = sort.remove();
            sort.add(a);
        }
        else {

        }
    }
    
    System.out.println(sort);
}
```

}

Comment: A "queue" really isn't supposed to be "sorted".  Q Why not just 1) use your LinkedList<int> (or an ArrayList<int>), 2) Add every other element from your input string (change "i++" to "i += 2", 3) sort the List when you're done?

Comment: Unrelated, but why are you doing `Integer.parseInt(s.charAt(i) + "")`?

Comment: @paulsm4, I'm not sure what you mean by sorting, could you elaborate please?

Comment: @OneCricketeer, it's so I can store each individual integer from the String into my queue

Comment: Why not make a loop from 1 to 6? You don't need a string

Comment: @Pippoot: your code has a variable named "sort"; so silly me thought you wanted the data "sorted".  ANYWAY: 1) you don't need a queue; 2) you can make the code a lot simpler/a lot shorter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just build the list differently. No queue required.

You can add half the numbers at the start, the add the rest in-between each.

```
List<Integer> nums = new ArrayList<>();

Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int limit = sc.nextInt(); // 6
int value = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < limit / 2; i++) {
  nums.add(value++);
}
for (int i = 1; i < limit; i+=2) {
  nums.add(i, value++);
}
System.out.println(nums); // [1, 4, 2, 5, 3, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just add them one after the other in a single loop.  The second element is simply the current one plus the offset where the offset is half the array length.

- read in the number as a string.
- and work with the character array of digits.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
String val = input.next();
List<Integer> result  =new ArrayList<>();

char[] digits = val.toCharArray();
int half = digits.length/2;
for(int i = 0; i < half; i++) {
    result.add(digits[i]-'0');
    result.add(digits[i+half]-'0');
}
System.out.println(result);
```

For an input of `123456`, prints

```
[1, 4, 2, 5, 3, 6]
```